# Do I have to remove the existing 6' fence posts to install an 8' metal fence?

Tags: fence, post

I would like to replace a 6 foot fence with a 8 foot fence.  The current fence has metal post.  Will I have to dig up the current post or can I weld an extension to the existing post.

Comment: I assume you are staying with metal?   What location are you in.  Most US cities will require a variance to go above 6ft for residential uses.

Comment: what kind of fence do you want? Do you know how to weld? What style of metal are the post are they? is this fence for a junk yard or a nice back yard?

Comment: If all else fails you can do the following: remove some of concrete or ground into which the posts are set, cut just below surface, weld new posts to leftovers of old posts, then either paint the welded joints, or cover them in concrete to protect them from rust.

Comment: If they are round posts, instead of welding, I'd look at finding 8' posts that are a slightly large diameter and slipping them over the current ones.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of structure, sure.  However it will be ugly, unless you are a very good welder, and take a lot of care dressing it after.

Remember too that most fence pipe is galvanized.  The fumes given off when you heat it are quite poisonous.

It may be a better idea to just buy chunks of pipe with an inside diameter that can slide over the existing post, or alternately, to make extension posts of the same diameter with a stub that will fit inside the existing post.  This latter method would allow you to do any welding in a shop setting (much easier).

Or instead of welding you could use epoxy glue, or hole and bolt to join the pipes.

Comment: Depending on the cost benifit/labor saved factor you could expand on @Sherwoods idea and slide an 8' pipe over your 6' pipe. Drill and tap a hole in the outer pipe both top and bottom. Insert a bolt to lock the two pipes together so it won't rattle. It will have a finished look with no welding.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did: Left the posts up. Put the new fence panel on the outside of the posts. Drilled holes in the fence and used deep u-bolts to attach the new fence panel to the old posts.